# R - Using column indexing in gather function

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm trying to use the gather function to combine multiple rows and lengthen my wide data. Example data below:

```
User ID    Book 1    Book 1_YN   Book 2   Book 2_YN   Book 3   Book3_YN   Book 4   Book 4_YN
1            ABC          Y      XYZ          N         LMN        Y 
2            XYZ          Y      DEF          Y      
3            ABC          N      XYZ          Y         TUV        N       HIJ     Y
```

Ideally, I want the data to look like the below table so I can summarize info about the books:

```
User ID    Book_Num    Book   Book_YN
1           Book 1     ABC      Y
1           Book 2     XYZ      N
1           Book 3     LMN      Y
2           Book 1     XYZ      Y
2           Book 2     DEF      Y
3           Book 1     ABC      N
3           Book 2     XYZ      Y
3           Book 3     TUV      Y
3           Book 4     HIJ      Y
```

When I try to use column indexing in the gather function...

`data_clean <- gather(data, Book_Num, Book, data[c(2,4,6,8)]`

I get the following error:
"Error: `data[c(2,4,6,8)]` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a list"

Anyone know what that error means and/or if there is a better way to handle this task?

*Edited to change images to tables

Comment: Please add a reproducible example using `dput` and not as images. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah, I updated the images to tables. Hope that helps to some degree. I will refer to that documentation for my questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns("^Book \\d+$", "^Book \\d+_YN$"), na.rm = TRUE,
     value.name = c("Book", "Book_YN"), variable.name = "Book_Num")[, 
      Book_Num := paste("Book", Book_Num)][order(`User ID`)]
#   User ID Book_Num Book Book_YN
#1:       1   Book 1  ABC       Y
#2:       1   Book 2  XYZ       N
#3:       1   Book 3  LMN       Y
#4:       2   Book 1  XYZ       Y
#5:       2   Book 2  DEF       Y
#6:       3   Book 1  ABC       N
#7:       3   Book 2  XYZ       Y
#8:       3   Book 3  TUV       N
#9:       3   Book 4  HIJ       Y
```

---

Or using `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    rename_at(-1, ~ str_replace(., ' (\\d+)_YN', '_YN \\1')) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -`User ID`, names_to = c(".value", "Book_Num"),
      names_sep=" ", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(Book_Num = str_c('Book ', Book_Num))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
#  `User ID` Book_Num Book  Book_YN
#      <int> <chr>    <chr> <chr>  
#1         1 Book 1   ABC   Y      
#2         1 Book 2   XYZ   N      
#3         1 Book 3   LMN   Y      
#4         2 Book 1   XYZ   Y      
#5         2 Book 2   DEF   Y      
#6         3 Book 1   ABC   N      
#7         3 Book 2   XYZ   Y      
#8         3 Book 3   TUV   N      
#9         3 Book 4   HIJ   Y
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`User ID` = 1:3, `Book 1` = c("ABC", "XYZ", "ABC"
), `Book 1_YN` = c("Y", "Y", "N"), `Book 2` = c("XYZ", "DEF", 
"XYZ"), `Book 2_YN` = c("N", "Y", "Y"), `Book 3` = c("LMN", NA, 
"TUV"), `Book 3_YN` = c("Y", NA, "N"), `Book 4` = c(NA, NA, "HIJ"
), `Book 4_YN` = c(NA, NA, "Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! Do you know if it's possible to use column indexing with the melt function instead of the wildcard expression? I'm wondering for cases where the column names are different (i.e. don't all have book in them) yet I still want to combine them.

Comment: @SummerLover2017  Yes, that is possible